# Area51 proposal on Chemistry is nearing launch

Tags: discussion

I'm not a regular here, though I lurk a lot. I just wanted to drop a line to say that the [Area51 proposal on Chemistry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4964/chemistry?referrer=s30-Mjm5p4wYaNpjIO5Bmg2) is nearing launch (91% commitment). If you're interested in it, please feel free to go read there and maybe help us by committing!

Comment: We do get a fair number of chemistry questions and it'll be nice to have a place where they can find a good home.

Comment: Same applies to [Biology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12502/biology?referrer=EA97ULoEKd4aJXI9mkpxVQ2). BTW I'll commit as soon as I'll clear my other commitments.

Comment: It's $ \large{ \bf{ %100 } } $ now and I can't wait any more to go for it!... :)

Answer (score 5):

They are at 11 % right now, any commitment would help!